# Passing between two hidden fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I seem to have an issue with passing a value between two hidden fields.

I'm using a jquery plugin for for geolocation from google maps. The plugin uses a fieldset which includes two hidden fields, one for lat and one for lon. Each time then pin is moved the two values change, which is definitely happening and can be viewed in the developer tools.

I have a form that I'm bringing all of my values into to be sent to a php file all in one go. I've managed to get it working for all the other inputs I need but this one just wont work.

Heres the map with the two hidden fields. The hidden classes come with a value of 20 preset which changes.

```
<div class="gllpMap">Google Maps</div>
<input type="hidden" class="gllpLatitude" value="20"/>
<input type="hidden" class="gllpLongitude" value="20" />
<input type="hidden" class="gllpZoom" value="3"/>
</div>
```

And here is my search that is going to be sent to the php.

```
<form method="post" action="getData.php">

 <input type="text" name="username" class="mySearch" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="fromTest" id="fromTest"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="untilTest" id="untilTest"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="long" id="long"/>


 <input type="submit" class="myButton" value="">

 </form>
```

For some reason I just cant get this to work. What I'm looking for is the simplest way to get this lat and long to equal the values set by the two hidden fields. The simpler the better, I'm pretty new to coding and this is just a first mock-up which I hope to revisit properly when I have more time available.

Comment: Can you post the php code too?

Comment: I dont think the PHP code is relevant, its a search function for twitter. The getData.php just takes that form and sets variables with the values within the php function. The fromTest and untilTest fields are working perfectly and working in the PHP.

If theres another reason for it let me know! I could post it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take and set the value using JQuery .val()

```
$("#lat").val($(".gllpLatitude").val());
$("#long").val($(".gllpLongitude").val());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ck9eh/)

Comment: This works great! Only one issue, I seem to have to press the button twice to get the new lat long value being created by the map. Is there a way to get around this and do it on the first click?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I do not know how is the map working. This code, just get the value of a parameter and assign it to an other